# Intl.DateTimeFormat shows time being 24:59

Tags: javascript, date

Hey everyone| just checking if I am doing something wrong. The code below gives me time = 24:59, in Prague (GMT+1). Using Chrome.

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  'en',
  {
     weekday: 'long',
     month: 'long',
     day: 'numeric',
     hour: 'numeric',
     minute: 'numeric',
     hour12: false
  }
 ).format(new Date('2020-03-11T23:59:00Z')
) 
// "Thursday, March 12, 24:59"
```

When using the .getHours() I will get a correct value of 0 though.

```
new Date('2020-03-11T23:59:00Z'); // Thu Mar 12 2020 00:59:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
new Date('2020-03-11T23:59:00Z').getHours(); // 0
```

Thanks for suggestions, I didn't found any related issues about this.

Tomas

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code gives me `"Thursday, March 12, 00:59"` in Firefox and `"Thursday, March 12, 24:59"` in Chrome (80.0.3987.149)

There appears to be a bug open for Chrome 80 https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/29828561?hl=en, open since February, but not much is said about whether it will be fixed and how. Consider upvoting it.

According to a comment posted there, you could work around the issue by replacing the `hour12` property with `hourCycle: 'h23'`.

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  'en',
  {
     weekday: 'long',
     month: 'long',
     day: 'numeric',
     hour: 'numeric',
     minute: 'numeric',
     hourCycle: 'h23'
  }
 ).format(new Date('2020-03-11T23:59:00Z')
)
// "Thursday, March 12, 00:59"
```

This seems to do the trick for me

Comment: The difference between h11, h12 and h23, h24 is described in [*What are the differences between the hourCycle options in Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258401/what-are-the-differences-between-the-hourcycle-options-in-date-prototype-tolocal)

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be the default setting for HourCycle and langauge `en`, which you'd expect to be `h23`, but Chrome is using `h24`. You can fix it as [described by toniedzwiedz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887094/257182), or you can provide a suitable country code for the language tag to force the HourCycle to default to `h23`, say GB:

```js
let d = new Date(2020,2,1,0,23);
let opts = { hour12: false, hour: 'numeric' };

console.log(d.toLocaleString('en', opts)); // 24 (Chrome), 00 others
console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-GB', opts)); // 00 all
```

Comment: Good stuff. Dates are hard 

Comment: @toniedzwiedz—yes, but ECMA-262 doesn't help much and [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) arguably makes things worse as much is implementation dependent. The [*temporal* proposal*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) should help.