# Issue: Fullcalendar shows 24 as midnight instead of 00:00

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, date-formatting, fullcalendar-4

For some reason, Fullcalendar is showing events that start past midnight as e.g. '24:15'. We want it to show '00:15'. I think this is a new issue, because we have had the calendar for a year, and this is the first I'm  hearing of it. But I can't find anything about how to solve it.
[image: Event in the calendar starting at 24:15]

We are using fullcalendar v4.2.0. I did not write the original code, but I'm fairly familiar with it. We fetch events using a REST API, and we're using ServiceNow. When using the 12-hour format (am/pm), it shows 12a15. I tried changing the eventTimeFormat, but had no luck. This is part of the client script:

```
    /* Calendar */
c.funcs.loadCalendar = function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    c.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid','timeGrid', 'list'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek,listMonth'
        },
        buttonText: {
            dayGridMonth: 'Month',
            timeGridWeek: 'Week',
            timeGridDay: 'Day',
            listWeek: 'List Week',
            listMonth: 'List Month',
            today: 'Today'
        },
        editable: false,
        eventTimeFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false
        },
        eventOverlap: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        weekNumbers: true,
        // Scripted REST API which sends Start and End date-time of current view as parameters and gets current events. 
        //events: '/api/tnas/fullcalendar_fetch_data',

        events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/tnas/fullcalendar_fetch_data',
                headers: {
                    'X-UserToken': window.g_ck // Authorization
                },
                params: {
                    systems: c.vars.selectedSystems.map(function(system) { return system.value; }).toString(),
                    excludedTypes: c.vars.types.filter(function(type) {return !type.checked}).map(function(type) { if(!type.checked) return type.type   }).toString(),
                    start: info.start,
                    end: info.end
                }
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                successCallback(data.result.events);
            }).error(function(data, status) {failureCallback(data)});
        },
        loading: function(isLoading) {
            c.vars.calendarIsLoading = isLoading;
            $scope.$evalAsync();
        },
        // When event is rendered and put into the DOM, add a tippy.js tooltip to that element.
        eventRender: function(info) {
            tippy(info.el, {
                theme: 'light-border',
                content: info.event.extendedProps.tooltipContent,
                arrow: true,
                animation: 'fade',
                flip: false,
                boundary: 'window'
            });
        },
        eventClick: function(info){
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault();
            var p = $scope.data.page_id || 'form';
            var url = '/sp?id=' + p + '&table=' + info.event.extendedProps.table + '&sys_id=' + info.event.id + '&view=sp';
            window.open(url, "_blank");
        },
        navLinks: true,
        navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
            //c.calendar.gotoDate(date);
            c.calendar.changeView('timeGridDay', date);
        }
    });

    c.calendar.render();
}
/* Calendar End */
```

JSON of the event:

```
title: "Metro IN-Applikasjoner - test"
number: "SREL0004789"
start: "2020-04-15 00:15:00"
end: "2020-04-16 14:00:00"
downtime_start: ""
downtime_end: ""
className: "SystemRelease"
type: "system_release"
table: "release"
id: "4a393c2b298c54903eaa786081948e7c"
state: "New"
state_reason: null
downtime_type: "Soft"
color: "rgb(163, 222, 255, 0.5)"
tooltipContent: "<div style='text-align:left; font-size:1.5em'><p>Metro IN-Applikasjoner - test</p><p><strong>Start:</strong>   00:15, 15. apr 20</p><p><strong>End:</strong>   14:00, 16. apr 20</p></div>"
```

Hopefully someone has experienced the same issue before. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show an example of the actual event data which causes this issue please? In JSON format, the way fullCalendar would receive it, please. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson I've added the JSON event to the post now. Logged from the successful callback, 'data.result.events'.

Comment: FYI that is not JSON format, but it's sufficient, thanks. I'm able to reproduce the issue: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNjbWWq . Not sure how to fix it yet, need to think.

Comment: Ok, I'd say this was an internal bug in fullCalendar. It still occurs in 4.4 (the latest released version): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abvdqgG. Surprising because you'd think it would be obvious. I would suggest reporting it as a bug - see here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . There's not much anyone on StackOverflow can do about it, I don't think. It's up to the developers of fullCalendar to fix it, as far as I can see.

Comment: It could be related to hourCycle, which may hang off the detected language. In the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), where the hour cycle is 24, then 00 is shown as 24. An hour cycle of 23 shows 00. The detected language can cause the value to change. FullCalendar uses a mix of what look like cut–down versions moment.js and Luxon, and Luxon heavily uses the Intl object for its functionality. Just a guess… `console.log(new Date(2020,0).toLocaleString('en',{hourCycle: 'h24'}););`

Comment: Also see [*Intl.DateTimeFormat shows time being 24:59*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886186/intl-datetimeformat-shows-time-being-2459).

Comment: @RobG just for info, fullCalendar only uses momentJS or Luxon if you add those plugins, they're optional. OP's code is using the default functionality which relies on the native JS Date object. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting (and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-library more widely).

Comment: @ADyson—the default FullCalendar package includes parts of moment.js and Luxon, I just assumed it was used generally.

Comment: @RobG No problem. They're plugin files which connect fullCalendar to moment/Luxon, I believe. To use them in fullCalendar as described in those links, you have to add the appropriate original library file (either moment or Luxon) _and_ the plugin file provided by fullCalendar to your page, and then load the plugin via fullCalendar's options when you initialise the calendar. Otherwise is just uses native JS Date objects for its date/time parsing and formatting functionality.

Comment: @RobG, and ADyson, thanks a bunch, both of you. Replacing the hour12 property with hourCycle: 'h23' in eventTimeFormat did the trick!

Comment: @AstridK.M. Glad you solved it. You should add that in the Answers section properly below, so others can vote on it, and so others with the same problem can find the solution more easily (as questions with accepted answers show up more often in searches). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed: Replacing the hour12 property with hourCycle: 'h23' in eventTimeFormat did the trick!

```
    eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        hourCycle: 'h23'
    },
```