# Date.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: false}) is providing midnight as 24

Tags: javascript, date

The code

```js
const d = new Date('2021-08-04T18:33:43.0000000Z')
  .toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: false, timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"}) 
console.log(d)
```

is providing result as `"8/5/2021, 24:03:43"`.
Here '24' hr should be shown as '00' hr. Is this a `toLocaleString` function issue?

I need to use as above syntax because, date format should be browser language date format and time should be 24 hr format.

For other language its works fine, for example GB

```js
const d = new Date('2021-08-04T18:33:43.0000000Z')
  .toLocaleString('en-GB', {hour12: false, timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"}) 
console.log(d)
```

will provide result as `"05/08/2021, 00:03:43"`.

So can someone help me how to get the correct 24 hour format time by using `toLocaleString` function?

Comment: Seems to be an issue only in Chrome.

Comment: And Edge since that is also Chromium

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems to be a  bug in INTL ECMA specifications, which should be fixed in ECMA2021.

It may be a Chromium only issue

In the mean time you can add `hourCycle: 'h23'` to your parameters to force the 00 since `h24` is default for SOME locales when `hour12: false` is specified

https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/726

> The root cause of this issue comes from [this change in Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/07437481c7fb47d7e84e4ce04008339d817e08ce). It introduces support for the hourCycle option in Intl.DateTimeFormat.
> The four supported values are "h11", "h12", "h23", or "h24" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)) and the difference between h23 and h24 is precisely if midnight should be displayed as 00 (h23) or 24 (h24)

[What are the differences between the hourCycle options in Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258401/what-are-the-differences-between-the-hourcycle-options-in-date-prototype-tolocal/55823036#55823036)

Comment: I see 24 in Chrome 91 on Win 10

Comment: Yes, it seems to be only in Chrome/en-US, not an issue in Safari, Firefox, Opera. I'm not a fan of allowing *toLocaleString* to do whatever, I much prefer *formatToParts* and do the actual formatting myself (or use a library…). :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `hourCycle: 'h23'` option to force `0-23` hours format.

```js
> new Date('2021-08-04T18:33:43.0Z').toLocaleString('en-US', { hourCycle: 'h23'})
"8/5/2021, 00:33:43"
```