# Javascript Date() returns hour over 24

Tags: javascript, date

In my timezone, at the moment it's (12:40 AM /00:40).

Date() gives me the hour over 24 as my output looks like `7/8/2022, 24:40:00`, how can I fix that?

```js
const dateTimezone = new Date("2022-07-08T00:40:00").toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hour12: false
})
  
console.log(dateTimezone)
```

Comment: I see this output `7/8/2022, 00:46:03`

Comment: this is the output i see: 7/8/2022, 24:47:33

Comment: try adding `hourCycle: 'h23'`

Comment: How exactly do you run the code?

Comment: Seems to be different across runtimes. Gives me the 24:xx:xx on V8.

Comment: `new Date('2022/01/01 12:40').toLocaleString(...` shows as 00:40:00 for me

Comment: when you use `hour12: false` chrome sets hourCycle to h24 and some browsers set it to h23, h24 means from 1-24, theres an issue on it here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1045791

Comment: this does it for me, thanks @dippas

Comment: Is 1-24 hours a US thing? Using "en-GB" shows `08/07/2022, 00:40:00`.

Comment: @gre_gor most likely since the default hc for `en-GB` is set to `h23` even on V8; `en-US` uses `h12`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [ECMA spec](https://402.ecma-international.org/8.0/#sec-initializedatetimeformat) defines the `hour12` option to toggle the hour cycle between either the values `h11` and `h23` or `h12` and `h24`.

This is enforced by Chromium's V8, but not SpiderMonkey and JavascriptCore. Hence the output from the snippet in the question will not be reproducible in most major non-Chromium browsers.

See the [open issue on ECMA402](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/402) on this topic.

---

Since the default hour cycle for `en-US` is `h12`, if running on V8, `hour12: false`, will toggle it to `h24`.

To produce the output you desire consistently across runtimes, you can manually set the hour cycle option to use `h23` in `.toLocaleString`.

The example below should always show `00` for the hour across all runtimes:

```js
const dateTimezone = new Date("2022-07-08T00:40:00").toLocaleString('en-US', {
    hourCycle: 'h23'
})
  
console.log(dateTimezone)
```

Comment: ECMA-402 defines the options, but it does not define how they behave, that is left (more or less) to the [Unicode CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/index). Setting *hour12* to false does not necessarily change the hour cycle to 24. They are separate options. The hour cycle is more reliably set by the *hc* option in the language tag (in this case, 'en-US-u-hc-h23`, which obviates the need for an options object), otherwise the hour cycle option can clash with the format associated with the laguage tag chosen and which one wins is anyone's guess.

Comment: @RobG as I explained, according to spec, the `hour12` flag toggles the hour cycle between either 11-23 or 12-24. So yes, if the locale's default is h11 and `hour12` is false, it should theoretically change to h23. Also according to spec, if the `hc` option is set in the locale string, it should take precedence over the `hourCycle` option.

Comment: "*if the locale's default is h11 and hour12 is false, it should theoretically change to h23*". Where is that specified? [ECMA-402](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-intl.datetimeformat.prototype.resolvedoptions) says that setting the hour cycle should set hour12 to a suitable value, not the other way around. Setting hour12 to false might set the hour cycle to either hc23 or hc24 depending on the language, what the CLDR suggests and the implementation's code. Here's the [page for en-US](https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=en_US), hour cycle isn't mentioned.

Comment: @RobG see #40.d in [402](https://402.ecma-international.org/8.0/#sec-initializedatetimeformat), where hcDefault is the default hc for the locale

Comment: Cool, so "theoretically" is redundant (theoretically). But in practice I have found  that the host default language and the one supplied as "locale" (a silly misnomer) seem to conflict in various situations.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems 40.3 "If hc is null, then…" is ignored by some browsers at least. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72920612/257182) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258401/what-are-the-differences-between-the-hourcycle-options-in-date-prototype-tolocal). I'm also aware of [*Intl.DateTimeFormat shows time being 24:59*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886186/intl-datetimeformat-shows-time-being-2459).

Comment: @RobG yes... as I also explained in my answer, this part of the spec is enforced by V8, but not by SpiderMonkey or JSCore

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am not sure why this question is incorrectly closed. This is very much valid and there is no typo as it says.